# Update ubuntu phone from Nexus 4 directly

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

im using the ubuntu touch/phone on my new nexus 4 (ordered it to try ubuntu on it).
I was asking myself how i can update the phone with daily builds.

I know about the http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/ preinstalled images but also saw that on my phone, if i go to settings/updates/ show me that there is an update available. 
If i try this, it says "you can update from version 0 to version 201..." and its about 250MB of download size, after a few minutes ubuntu tell me to reboot my phone. If i accept that i found myself in the bootloader. If i reboot from here the phone is not updated. If i search again for updates (settings/updates/) the same update shows up.

Is the build in update function only a dummy? Or am i doing wrong here? Do i have to choose another option in the bootloader to install the latest updates?

Or is an update only possible from the shell with the andriod device bridge (ADB)?

Answer (score 0):

Update:  This functionality is working now, as long as you use the `ubuntu-system` option when flashing your phone.

---

Original answer:

It doesn't do anything yet.  Rick Spencer, VP of Ubuntu Engineering, writes about it as a goal [on his blog](http://theravingrick.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/the-big-rocks-of-august.html) for end of August.

> The first big rock is Image Based Upgrades. Today, when we "bless" a new image, one must use a tool on your desktop called "phablet-flash" to update to that new image. After August, the phone will download updates over wireless and install them without requiring a connection to the desktop.

You can follow progress on this issue here: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-1305-image-based-updates